# How to restrict javascript event handling to only on event triggerd by the dom element

Tags: javascript

I want stop event propagation to only on function in the code instead of stopping and not the rest of the events triggered it is not possible using e.stopeventporpogation

Comment: Where is your code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't restrict it to single function, instead what you can do is to write the function to be triggered before `e.stopeventpropogation` and the rest can be after that line